# Express with ejs serverless host with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, ejs, serverless

I'm trying to deploy an express app with ejs view-engine as an AWS Lambda function using serverless
I'm really new to serverless framework and need some guidelines.

PROBLEM: The deployment is successfull but I get `{"message": "Internal server error"}` from AWS endpoint

Here's my Express `server.js`

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index',{data: {name: user}, error: null});
}

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

And `serverless.yml`

```
org: dk013
app: wforecast
service: wforecast
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
functions:
  app:
    handler: app.handler
    events: 
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Any guidelines on what is wrong with my code/config or how to do it teh right way is appreciated

Comment: did you check the logs on cloudwatch??

Comment: turn on API logs and check cloudwatch

Comment: No I didn't. you're right...I should've.Be back if I need help with what I find there. As I said before I'm new to AWS and serverless framework. But this was a really noob mistake.

Comment: No such thing. Serverless is so new everyone is a noob. Don't worry about it

Comment: A few things that come to mind - you probably need to explicitly require `ejs` - else I don't see how it will be packaged in the lambda. Additionally that `public` static directory may cause issues since there isn't a directory structure to match. Just guesses so.

Comment: Can you come and update the community on what the issue was for other people running into this issue?

Comment: @Sigex Actually I have given up on that after a few trails. maybe I should just remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct cache options to serve you static bundles; here is a general example:

```
const cacheOptions = {
    etag: true,
    lastModified: true,
    setHeaders: (res, path) => {
      const hashRegExp = new RegExp('\\.[0-9a-zA-z]{8}\\.');
      if (path.endsWith('.html')) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
      } else if (hashRegExp.test(path)) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=31536000');
      }
    }
  }
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './build'), cacheOptions));
```